# Encrypt with Cryptico.js, Decrypt with OpenSSL

Tags: javascript, encryption, openssl, rsa, cryptico

I am creating a public/private key on the server, sending the key to the JavaScript client where it encrypts a users password.  The client sends the password to the server, and the server uses the private key to decrypt it, but the password is coming back null.  I have verified all values supporting the situation are correct, so it's something with the encryption/decryption specifically.  Where am I going wrong?

Possibly, is cryptico.js not compatible with php openssl?

Library Info:

https://github.com/wwwtyro/cryptico

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-new.php

Here are relevant code snippets:

**PHP - create public/private key**

```
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 2048,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);

// Extract the private key from $res to $privateKey
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privateKey);

// Extract the public key from $res to $publicKey
$publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$publicKey = $publicKey["key"];
```

**JavaScript - Client encrypts data with public key.**

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data = new FormData();
xhr.open('POST', '/signUp2.php');
data.append('user', User);

var encryptedPassword = cryptico.encrypt(password, localStorage["publicKey"]);
data.append('password', encryptedPassword.cipher);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
    {
        var jsonArray = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        if(jsonArray[0] == "0")
        {
            alert("Account created.  You may now sign in.");
        }
        else
            alert("Error Code: " + jsonArray[0]);
    }
}
xhr.send(data);
```

**PHP - Server recieves encrypted password and attemps to decrypt unsuccessfully**

```
openssl_private_decrypt($encryptedPassword, $decryptedPassword, $row[1]);
```

Comment: You are using sha512 on the server side. However I read that native Javascript only supports AES 256bit encryption and in the documentation, it brings an example for interoperability with aes 256bit Keys: http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/#Interoperability

Answer (score 4):

cryptico.js could work with openssl, but we have to modify it a bit.

it don't directly recognize the public key in pem format (which openssl use). we have to extract the 'n' and 'e' part of a public key in php side:

```
$key = openssl_pkey_new(array( 
  'private_key_bits' => 1024,
  'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
  'digest_alg' => 'sha256'
));

$detail = openssl_pkey_get_details($key);
$n = base64_encode($detail['rsa']['n']);
$e = bin2hex($detail['rsa']['e']);
```

also, cryptico.js hardcoded the 'e' part of a public key (see definition of publicKeyFromString in api.js), so we need to fix this:

```
my.publicKeyFromString = function(string)
{
  var tokens = string.split("|");
  var N = my.b64to16(tokens[0]);
  var E = tokens.length > 1 ? tokens[1] : "03";
  var rsa = new RSAKey();
  rsa.setPublic(N, E);
  return rsa
}
```

now we are able to encrypt strings:

```
var publicKey = "{$n}|{$e}",
    encrypted = cryptico.encrypt("plain text", publicKey);
```

job is not finished yet. the result of cryptico.encrypt is NOT simply encrypted by RSA. indeed, it was combined of two parts: an aes key encrypted by RSA, and the cipher of the plain text encrypted with that aes key by AES. if we only need RSA, we could modify my.encrypt:

```
my.encrypt = function(plaintext, publickeystring, signingkey)
{
  var cipherblock = "";
  try
  {
    var publickey = my.publicKeyFromString(publickeystring);
    cipherblock += my.b16to64(publickey.encrypt(plaintext));
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    return {status: "Invalid public key"};
  } 
  return {status: "success", cipher: cipherblock};
}
```

now we are able to decrypt the cipher with openssl:

```
$private = openssl_pkey_get_private("YOUR PRIVATE KEY STRING IN PEM");
// $encrypted is the result of cryptico.encrypt() in javascript side
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, $private);
// now $decrypted holds the decrypted plain text
```

Comment: I'm getting an empty string for `$e = bin2hex($detail['rsa']['e']);`. Is this to be expected at all?

Comment: @JVE999 maybe your openssl extension is not correctly installed? if php can't find openssl.conf, it's not able to generate keys, but still able to do encrypt/decrypt stuff. check http://us1.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Comment: I am trying to automate an IP camera activation - I am not able to modify any javascript code, so I cannot modify the encrypt function. Any way to change things on the server side only?